# re-arranging vertex in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

```
df

network  bus_unit   outage
A        Online     4
B        Internal   5
A        Finance    6
B        IT         5
A       IT         6
A       Marketing  40
```

I need to greate a igraph which I can do with something like this:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df)
plot(g,  
     layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,  
     vertex.label = V(g) $name,
     vertex.label.color= "black", 
     edge.arrow.size=1, 
     edge.curved=FALSE, 
     edge.label=df$outage)
```

My problem is that I like to show the network A ontop of the graph since it is the culprit. Is there anyway to organize this igraph, move vertex's around etc.

thanks for your help.

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2012-10/msg00030.html

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold` to `plot()`, you're giving it a function for building the layout.  But you can also set up the layout *outside* of `plot()` and directly manipulate it - it's a simple matrix of coordinates.

```
# Create an initial layout
bad.a.layout <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)

# ... it's really just a matrix of coordinates, with each row
# corresponding to a vertex
bad.a.layout
plot(g, layout = bad.a.layout)

# Tweak arbitrarily - e.g., bump Network A nodes up a bit on the y-axis
bad.a.layout[V(g)$network %in% "A", 2] <- bad.a.layout[V(g)$network %in% "A", 2] + 10
plot(g, layout = bad.a.layout)
```

Of course, there's no guarantee that that will actually *look good*.  But that's a basic approach to modifying layouts to suit you.  If it's a one-off project, manual manipulation might be fine.  Otherwise, you'll probably want to look into algorithms more deeply (which has proven a bit of a rabbit hole for me, but you might have better luck).

Side note: I almost always set up my layouts outside of the plot function, even when I don't want to manipulate them.  With even medium-sized graphs, it can save a lot of time to not recalculate it every time you run the plot.